# How fast do I have to fly vertically up to pause sunset?

Tags: everyday-life, astronomy, earth, geometry, sun

I'm standing on the famous Laguna Beach in southern Los Angeles to watch the sunset on December 18th (33.541679°N 117.777214°W, 0m elevation, 16:44 PST). Now, from my perspective at the shore, the sun's lower edge cuts the horizon and begins to disappear. Astonished by this spectacular view, I want to preserve this moment with my drone which has just took off. Neglecting all atmospherical effects on sunlight and orbital revolution of earth around the sun, how fast do I need to lift the drone vertically upward to pause this view of sun's lower edge cutting horizon? Is the speed needed a function of time?

I used a quite complicated trigonometric method to get a result that this vertical velocity is a function of time. At t=1s, I only need 1.65cm/s; at t=360s, I need almost 6m/s. I'm not sure if I have handled the effect of latitude (34°) and earth's axial tilt (23.44°) correctly. Lots of thanks to anyone who could verify this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Assume you are at the topmost point in this diagram. You last see the sun when the light glances off the horizon and reaches you. Notice the horizon is moving away from you as the earth is rotating. So your drone should move up and be at the vertex of this right-angled triangle to catch the horizon. From the triangle, we get
$$h=R\left(\sec\theta-1\right)$$

A quick calculation shows the value of theta is only $3.5^\circ$ (or $0.056 \ rad<<1)$ even when your drone crosses the troposphere ($h\approx10\ km$, $R\approx6400\ km$) which is likely the highest your drone could ever fly. Now $\theta=\omega t$ where $\omega$ is the angular speed of the earth's rotation.

$$h=R\left(\sec\omega t-1\right)$$
$$\dot{h}=R\omega\sec\omega t \tan \omega t$$
Applying small angle approximation, $\sec x\approx1$ and $\tan x\approx x$
, the vertical velocity of the drone is:
$$\dot{h}=R\omega^2 t$$
And the vertical acceleration needed is
$$\ddot{h}=R\omega^2\approx 3.3\ cms^{-2}\approx0.0033\ g$$

And of course, the radius of the circle depends on latitude and axial tilt and time of year. But the maximum acceleration you would ever need is  $0.0033\ g$, which is well below the amount of thrust a drone can generate ([video](https://youtu.be/YD7g8-tYBJY?si=azxKH2UepoYok1G3&t=838)).